# Multiple axis does not work on Highcharts 4

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a function that adds another axis and serie to chart dynamically. It used to work well in Highcharts 3. Then i upgraded to Highcharts 4, but it adds axis but does not add serie.

```
    chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
        id: tempId,
        title: {
            text: tempName
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        lineColor: serie.color,
        opposite: opposition
    });

    var lbl = getLabelStatus_<?=$id?>(id);      

    chart.addSeries({
        name: tempName,
        type: serie.type,
        color: serie.color,
        yAxis: tempId,
        data: serie.data,
        dashStyle: serie.options.dashStyle,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: lbl,
            rotation: serie.options.dataLabels.rotation
        }
    });
```

Did they change something about axis in v4? How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Defaulty it works properly, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-addaxis/ so please isolate your example from custom code and recreate as live demo on jsfiddle.net

Comment: I am confused how the problem equates to "Multiple axis does not work on Highcharts 4". You state that it adds the axis. So clearly that works.  You need to get more specific about the problem - check for errors, check the axis object content after it's added, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ;

```
data : serie.options.data,
```